# PHP based web application and mass mailing

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I have developed a web application where students across the country come and register for some academic purpose. The users are expected to be around 100k within next year.

I need to send all of these people periodic mails. The web app is developed using codeigniter. The php script can run for 3000 seconds. But still the app is unable to send mails to more that 100 users.

The machine I run is in cloud and has got 256MB ram. I used the **free -m** command to check the memory usage but that doesnt seem to be a problem. Everything works fine for 10-20 mails.

What would be the best solutions? Is there any way I can transfer this job to some other app/program/shell script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very appropriate to get this out of your web server threads and into something that runs standalone.  Typically for stuff like this, I have tables in the DB where the appropriate information is written to from the web site, so when I am ready to e-mail, something on the backend can assemble the e-mails and send them out.  If you are sending out 100,000 e-mails, you are going to want something multithreaded.

It might be good in this case to use one of the many off-the-shelf tools for this, rather than reinventing the wheel.  We use an old version of Campaign Enterprise here, and I am able to throw queries at it which I can use to pull data from my web DB directly, over ODBC.  That may or may not work well for you, considering you are in the cloud.

**Edit:** You can also write a PHP script to do this and call PHP from the shell.  Perhaps you can get around your timeout limit this way?  (This is assuming you are referring to some service-level timeout.  If you are talking about the regular PHP timeout, this can worked around with `set_time_limit()`.)

Comment: Any freeware tools you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use some external service for your emails I would just setup a cronjob that sends a couple of emails every n seconds. Its pretty cumbersome to send a lot of emails with php as you have discovered. But the cronjob solution works everytime as far as I know.

So you have a list of emails/addresses and a cronjob that iterates that list and sends the emails.

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp is a viable candidate for this. Serving mail is a time-consuming task, and sending it up to 100k email addresses will be an arduous task for your server.

They provide an very capable PHP API.

https://developer.mailchimp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can send the emails yourself from a server, but that is only half the battle.

If you are sending bulk emails, as opposed to the transactional type, it's best to use a third party service that is already whitelisted on mail servers. The primary reason being, you might get blacklisted by the major mail servers as a spammer. If this happens, you will have to work with them individually to get removed from the blacklists.

Also if you are operating in the United States you should be familiar with CAN-SPAM: http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-Compliance-Guide-for-Business

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do with using [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or creating a [daemon process](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon).

Fork: By using the fork process you could batch the emails into groups and send them out. each batch could be in it's own fork child process

Daemon: By using a Daemon you could create a batch of emails and send them to be processed by the daemon. a daemon could run multiple batches at once.